# A pattern-matching function in PHP

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I'm looking for a function, class or collection of functions that will assist in the process of pattern matching strings as I have a project that requires a fair amount of pattern matching and I'd like something easier to read and maintain than raw preg_replace (or regex period).

I've provided a pseudo example in hopes that it will help you understand what I'm asking.

```
$subject = '$2,500 + $550 on-time bonus, paid 50% upfront ($1,250), 50% on delivery ($1,250 + on-time bonus).';
$pattern = '$n,nnn';
pattern_match($subject, $pattern, 0);
```

would return "$2,500".

```
$subject = '$2,500 + $550 on-time bonus, paid 50% upfront ($1,250), 50% on delivery ($1,250 + on-time bonus).';
$pattern = '$n,nnn';
pattern_match($subject, $pattern, 1);
```

would return an array with the values: [$2,500], [$1,250], [$1,250]

The function — as I'm trying to write — uses 'n' for numbers, 'c' for lower-case alpha and 'C' for upper-case alpha where any non-alphanumeric character represents itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would probably be best to create a function that interprets that as a regular expression, then formats the returned array more like you want it. Other ways would be much, much slower.

Comment: ...so a dummied-down regex wrapper?

Comment: Next thing you know, you'll want `n{from=2,to=4}`, `($|¥|€)`, etc. etc. and you'll be developing the 'Smarty' of regex matching. Are you sure you wanna go this route?

Comment: Your line « $pattern = "$n,nnn"; » is not correct since $n is not an available variable, it should be: « $pattern = '$n,nnn'; »

Comment: @freeyedboy: I know you were mostly kidding, but I actually don't hate that idea nearly as much as I hate smarty. I find regex unintuitive because I don't work with it regularly enough to develop an intimate, or even basic, understanding of it. A more readable and user friendly format wouldn't be a bad thing if it weren't at the expense of efficiency and speed.

Comment: if you hate smarty, try TinyButStrong   ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

// $match_all = false: returns string with first match
// $match_all = true:  returns array of strings with all matches

function pattern_match($subject, $pattern, $match_all = false)
{
  $pattern = preg_quote($pattern, '|');

  $ar_pattern_replaces = array(
      'n' => '[0-9]',
      'c' => '[a-z]',
      'C' => '[A-Z]',
    );

  $pattern = strtr($pattern, $ar_pattern_replaces);

  $pattern = "|".$pattern."|";

  if ($match_all)
  {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
  }
  else
  {
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
  }

  return $matches[0];
}

$subject = '$2,500 + $550 on-time bonus, paid 50% upfront ($1,250), 50% on delivery ($1,250 + on-time bonus).';
$pattern = '$n,nnn';

$result = pattern_match($subject, $pattern, 0);
var_dump($result);

$result = pattern_match($subject, $pattern, 1);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: +1, definitely an improvement over mine. I wasn't aware of `preg_quote()` until now!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This is an incomplete answer that doesn't hold up against several test patterns. See @Frosty Z's answer for a better solution.

```
<?php
    function pattern_match($s, $p, $c=0) {
        $tokens = array(
            '$' => '\$',
            'n' => '\d{1}',
            'c' => '[a-z]{1}',
            'C' => '[A-Z]{1}'
        );
        $reg = '/' . str_replace(array_keys($tokens), array_values($tokens), $p) . '/';
        if ($c == 0) {
            preg_match($reg, $s, $matches);
        } else {
            preg_match_all($reg, $s, $matches);
        }
        return $matches[0];
    }

    $subject = "$2,500 + $550 on-time bonus, paid 50% upfront ($1,250), 50% on delivery ($1,250 + on-time bonus).";

    $pattern = '$n,nnn';
    print_r(pattern_match($subject, $pattern, 0));
    print_r(pattern_match($subject, $pattern, 1));

    $pattern = 'cc-cccc';
    print_r(pattern_match($subject, $pattern));
    print_r(pattern_match($subject, $pattern, 1));
?>
```

**Output:**

```
$2,500

Array
(
    [0] => $2,500
    [1] => $1,250
    [2] => $1,250
)

on-time

Array
(
    [0] => on-time
    [1] => on-time
)
```

**Note:** Make sure to use single-quotes for your `$pattern` when it contains `$`, or PHP will try to parse it as a `$variable`.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't works with patterns like `cc/cc` (error) or `n.nnn` (returns '2.500', but as well '2,500', '2#500'...)

Comment: @Frosty Z: Yeah, I was in a rush to get an Answer up before I went out for lunch.  @Gumbo: It felt like a good idea at the time?

Comment: No problem, sometimes I have some flaws in my "quick answers" too :-)
Concerning Gumbo's comment, in fact `[A-Z]{1}` is equivalent to `[A-Z]` so adding `{1}` seems not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function with no regexp that should work ('C' and 'c' recognize only ascii chars) , enjoy:

```
function pattern_match($subject, $pattern, $result_as_array) {

    $pattern_len = strlen($pattern);
    if ($pattern_len==0) return false; // error: empty pattern

    // translate $subject with the symboles of the rule ('n', 'c' or 'C')
    $translate = '';
    $subject_len = strlen($subject);
    for ($i=0 ; $i<$subject_len ; $i++) {
        $x = $subject[$i];
        $ord = ord($x);
        if ( ($ord>=48) && ($ord<=57) ) { // between 0 and 9
            $translate .= 'n';
        } elseif ( ($ord>=65) && ($ord<=90) ) { // between A and Z
            $translate .= 'C';
        } elseif ( ($ord>=97) && ($ord<=122) ) { // between a and z
            $translate .= 'c';
        } else {
            $translate .= $x; // othre characters are not translated
        }
    }

    // now search all positions in the translated string

    // single result mode
    if (!$result_as_array) {
        $p = strpos($translate, $pattern);
        if ($p===false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return substr($subject, $p, $pattern_len);
        }
    }

    // array result mode
    $result = array();
    $p = 0;
    $n = 0;
    while ( ($p<$subject_len)  && (($p=strpos($translate,$pattern,$p))!==false) ) {
        $result[] = substr($subject, $p, $pattern_len);
        $p = $p + $pattern_len;
    }
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: Quite a good one! But why `if ($n>10) exit();` in the last while loop ?

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is [preg_match_all](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), although you'll need to use REGEX patterns for your pattern matching.

Comment: It seems that the OP wants to create his own patterns.

Comment: He explicitly said he didn't want to use regular expressions.

Comment: Could write a wrapper that converts his simpler patterns to REGEX (e.g. `str_replace('n', '[0-9]', $pattern);`), but short of completely re-inventing the REGEX wheel this is what he's got to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is a problem for regex. I understand your objections, but there's just no other way as efficient or simple in this case. This is an extremely simple matching problem. You could write a custom wrapper as jnpcl demonstrated, but that would only involve more code and more potential pitfalls. Not to mention extra overhead.